# Template literals like 'some ${string}' or "some ${string}" are not working

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I wanted to try using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and it’s not working: it’s displaying the literal variable names, instead of the values. I am using Chrome v50.0.2 (and jQuery).

### Example

```js
console.log('categoryName: ${this.categoryName}\ncategoryElements: ${this.categoryElements} ');
```

### Output

```
${this.categoryName}
categoryElements: ${this.categoryElements}
```

Comment: Use grave-accents ` and not single-quotes `'` or double-quotes `"`.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

#### JavaScript *template literals* require backticks, not straight quotation marks.

You need to use backticks (otherwise known as "grave accents" - which you'll find next to the 1 key [if you're using a QWERTY keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows)) - rather than single quotes - to create a template literal.

Backticks are common in many programming languages  but may be new to JavaScript developers.

Example:

```
categoryName="name";
categoryElements="element";
console.log(`categoryName: ${this.categoryName}\ncategoryElements: ${categoryElements} `)
```

Output:

```
VM626:1 categoryName: name 
categoryElements: element
```

See:

[Usage of the backtick character (`) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/what-is-the-usage-of-the-backtick-symbol-in-javascript)

Comment: Wow, you wouldn't believe how long it took me to find this. It is incredibly not evident this was the problem, especially sense the back tick is used to CREATE code segments in Markdown and the like. It's really easy to just think the back tick was a code marker and then mentally translate it to a single tick. Thank you, thank you kindly.

Comment: "If you're using a QWERTY keyboard" ...with a US layout. Some QWERTY layouts (e.g. QWERTY JIS) do not place the backtick there.

Comment: spec link: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-template-literals

Answer (score 4):

There are three quotation marks, but just one entrance is working which we can use as TEMPLATE LITERALS:

1. `" "` (<kbd>é</kbd> key on keyboard) is not working:

```
console.log("Server is running on port: ${PORT}")
```

2. `' '` (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> key on keyboard) is not working:

```
console.log('Server is running on port: ${PORT}')
```

3. `` ` ` `` (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Num96</kbd> key on keyboard) is working:

```
console.log(`Server is running on port: ${PORT}`)
```

[image: Screenshot of console.log(Server is running on port: ${PORT})]

Comment: Be careful, there are many different keyboard layouts! The British QWERTY layout has `"` as `shift + 2` with both `'` and `\`` having their own keys where no modifier is needed.