# vuejs setting API_URL inside dev.env.js gives unexpected "/$/"

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to set up API_URL variable to my dev.env.js file:

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  API_URL: '"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"'
})
```

and use it for api calls:

```
this.$http.get('${process.env.API_URL}/companyAddress')
```

and somehow my server response me with error:

```
Response {url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/$/companyAddress", 
ok: false, status: 405, statusText: "Method Not Allowed",
```

why is this happening? where does this "$" comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

> `this.$http.get('${process.env.API_URL}/companyAddress')`

And the answer is here: [ES6 / ECMA6 template literals - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245679/es6-ecma6-template-literals-not-working)

Comment: all right, now it works, the same stupid mistake again. Thanks!