# How to correctly pass parameters in http request

Tags: angular, rest, http, get, angular7

I am trying to pass a variable in my get request in Angular 7. how do you correctly set a variable in the middle of the url;

```
  export class dataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getUsers(userName){

    return this.http.get('/***/****/***/${userName}/keychain****);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/template_strings). You can attach your variables using the dollar syntax `${your_variable}`.

```
this.http.get(`/services/cxadmin/${userName}/japplegate/keychain');
```

Comment: Wow the issuse is you have to use grave accents or back ticks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
export class dataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getUsers(userName){

    return this.http.get(`/services/admin/${userName}/japplegate/key`);
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain what you did. A difference in punctuation is not necessarily obvious, and some fonts can make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

Wow can't belive the issue is you have to use backticks:
You need to use backticks (otherwise known as "grave accents" - which you'll find next to the 1 key) - rather than single quotes - to create a template literal.

Backticks are common in many programming languages but may be new to JavaScript developers. :[ES6 / ECMA6 template literals - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245679/es6-ecma6-template-literals-not-working)