# How to use formatted strings instead of concatenation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I tried using `${}` instead of the normal concatenation in JavaScript to make sentences after storing variables but it isn't running.

```
var firstName = "David";
var surname = "Israel";

console.log("My name is ${firstName} and my surname is ${surname}")
```

Comment: You need to use backticks `\`` - positioned to the left of the 1 on most keyboards

Comment: Does this answer your question: [ES6 / ECMA6 template literals - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37245679)

Comment: I get it now. I appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var surname = "Israel";

console.log(`My name is ${firstName} and my surname is ${surname}`)
```

Comment: I get it now. Thanks i'm still a beginner

Comment: all the best. If you are learning Js check out Brad Traversy at youtube.

Comment: Okayy, I'll do so