# Learning ES2015 and having difficulty with syntax, especially object methods

Tags: javascript, object, methods, ecmascript-6

I am working on a simple dog object with a name, bark method, and loudBark method.

- 'name' variable has to be global
- 'dog' object should be in global scope
- global variable 'loud' has to be used to create the 'loudBark' method
- im trying to practice shorthand too

This is where I am currently at:

```
const name = 'Cody';
const loud = 'loud';

const dog = {
    bark() { return 'ruff ruff!' },
    name,
    ['${loud}Bark']: function () {
        return this.bark.toUpperCase();
    },
};
```

If I call 'dog.loudBark' it says that is not a function, and I'm really confused, especially since I'm just now learning this new syntax and am used to the older one; I forgot what version specifically.

Comment: You're probably looking for `[loud + 'Bark']` or ``[`${loud}Bark`]`` - notice the backticks instead of apostrophes for the template string.

Comment: Use backticks not single quotes around `${loud}Bark`. (Typically the character is in the top left of the keyboard, just left of the numbers.)

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+template+literal+not+working) of [ES6 / ECMA6 template literals - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245679/es6-ecma6-template-literals-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

There's issue with your property assignment

To use string interpolation you need to place backticks(`), not singlequotes(')

so it will be

```
const dog = {
    bark() { return 'ruff ruff!' },
    name,
    [`${loud}Bark`]: function () {
        return this.bark.toUpperCase();
    },
};
```