# Multi-line string throws “`SyntaxError`: Invalid or unexpected token” when using single quotes

Tags: javascript

When following an online tutorial, it works but when I’m doing it myself, mine does not read the HTML code within the single quote below; the error is:

> app.js:15 Uncaught `SyntaxError`: Invalid or unexpected token.

```js
obj.forEach(({ title, image, id, price }) => {
  results += '<div class="product">(a bunch of html code)';
});
```

Comment: @RandyCasburn They’re called _backticks_, not backpacks. The comment markdown for them is `\`\\`\``.

Comment: Related: [ES6 / ECMA6 template literals - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37245679/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon - thanks Sebastian that was my auto-correction monster!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `""` or `''`, it works only for inline stuff. By inline stuff I mean you should open and close those guys on the same line.

```js
const str = "<p> Hello World </p>"
const str2 = '<p> Bye World </p>'
```

But if you want a string with multiple lines, then use ``` `` ```.

```js
const str3 = `
<h1> Hello World </h1>
<p> We are ready to go! <p>
`;
```

Comment: What do you mean by “inline stuff”? ``const multilineString = "hello\n\`` ⟨linebreak⟩ `world";` certainly works. It’d be more accurate to say that linebreaks require escaping when using `''` or `""`.