# javascript interpolation using saved variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, interpolation

I have a variable saved as object_id in javascript.
I want to target a data attribute by interpolating the object id in to the data attribute.

For example:

`$('[data-object-id="${object_id}"]')`
However this is not finding the attribute. The are no errors.
I've tried interpolating using '+' but found it quite fiddly in this instance.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+template+literal+not+working) of [ES6 / ECMA6 template literals - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37245679/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

For interpolation in string you need to use backticks(`) string. Try:

```
$(`[data-object-id="${object_id}"]`)
```