# Server started on port ${PORT} I can't find why it doesn't read .env

Tags: javascript, port

I don't understand why it says "Server started on port ${PORT}" instead of PORT 5000

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please post code as text and not as image ...

Comment: Single quotes `'` are not used for templating. Graves `\`` are.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Duplicate of [ECMAScript template literals like 'some ${string}' are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245679/ecmascript-template-literals-like-some-string-are-not-working)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change

```
'Server started on port ${PORT}'
```

to

```
`Server started on port ${PORT}`
```

documention: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals