# (dollar sign + curly brackets) template literal not working

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I'm working through a course and knew I had to use a template literal to get what I needed in the console. only when I finish it and save, it prints what I typed and didn't do its template literal thing... I can't find anything online and not sure where I went wrong.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to use backticks not single quotes `\`` not `'`. See the docs [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) *'Template literals are literals delimited with backtick (`\``) characters...'*

Comment: First, please add your code as text, not images. Second, template literals are written with backticks instead of single quotes.

Comment: Duplicate: [Template literals like 'some ${string}' or "some ${string}" are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245679/template-literals-like-some-string-or-some-string-are-not-working). Also, [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385519/include-dont-post-images-of-code-in-the-guide)