# can't write this symbol ${} in my backend

Tags: javascript

I can't right this symbol by my own
[image]

hello guys i'm a newbie
I know it's a simple symbol but I have to Copy Paste from other file if I want to write it. I can't write on my vscode and I use window it's always problem when it's in string. So how it fix it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template literals like 'some ${string}' or "some ${string}" are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245679/template-literals-like-some-string-or-some-string-are-not-working)

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:html]?

Comment: What does "can't write" mean? Your fingers don't reach the required key on the keyboard? When you press the key on the keyboard, nothing happens?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
`
```

not `'`.

It should look like this:

```
`your server is running on ${port}`
```