# dollar sign $ as an assignment operator for a value of string in vs code ( js ) does not work or highlighted

Tags: javascript, string, variables, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

```
function sayHello (userName)  {
    console.log ('Hello ${userName}') ;
}

sayHello ('Mena') ;

function sayHello (userName)  {
    console.log ('Hello ${userName}') ;
}

sayHello ('mena') ;
```

// i expected to show say ( Hello Mena  ) in the console //

Comment: [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) should be delimited with backtick (`) characters instead of double or single quotes. Note also that this does not make the $ an assignment operator.

Comment: [Template literals like 'some ${string}' or "some ${string}" are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245679/template-literals-like-some-string-or-some-string-are-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backticks(`) instead of (').

Example:

```js
function sayHello (userName) {
    console.log (`Hello ${userName}`);
}
```

Comment: @Sauabh Be aware of the formating! Backticks have a meaning in markdown text and isn't shown verbatim. You need it in a code segment, that can be solved by adding 4 spaces at the beginning of each line. Check the preview before publishing.