Unable to output variable in a string

I am trying to make it display the fullname variable and other variables but it wont show it just shows this on the screen, can anyone help me?

Am I doing something wrong and can someone point out my mistake If I am doing a mistake, also I use Visual studio code so it will become purple if it is a variable but it does not become purple.
I was expecting it to show the variable.

Typo. You're using string literals, not template literals. Fix your syntax and the code will work. Also note for future questions - please copy+paste the code as text. Images of code are not helpful for those reading your question, and it takes longer for you to create

${...} can only be used inside backticks, not inside double quotes.

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37245679/519413

Thanks alot, I didnt know because I am new to javascript.

"I didnt know because I am new to javascript - if you knew, you wouldn't have asked
