# Passing variable as link text in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm stucked in a simple variable, what i want to achieve is to have link text as variable.
my code:

```
 var ReadMore = myvar;

          $(this).empty().html(subStr);
          $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="linkReadMore">MY VARIABLE HERE</a>')
```

i've tried in many ways but i'm doing something wrong for sure, can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Dear can you please share the full  information or code.

Comment: _"i've tried in many ways"_ - Why is there none of them in your question?

Comment: String concatenation is part of every JavaScript tutorial out there -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put variables inside javascript strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790811/how-do-i-put-variables-inside-javascript-strings)

Comment: Possible dupe: [How to interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript, without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not concatenate the variable inside anchor tag.

```
var myvar = "ReadMore";
```

You have to concatenate your variable like this

```
$(this).append('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="linkReadMore">'+myvar+'</a>');
```

Comment: i've tried this but missing " ' ' ".......thank you so much, i will accept this answer in 7 minutes