# Named variable appearing as string

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

```
const sayHi = (name) => {
console.log('Hello there ${name}')
}

module.exports = sayHi
```

[image: Here is what it looks like]

In the console.log function I am calling the variable name but it is picking it as a string. I am learning nodejs and i dont know why i am getting this problem.
ps: There is a mistake with the screenshot in terms of the variable name but that is not the problem.

Comment: Read about [JavaScript template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: The console message is not from that piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32695337/10776298

With Node.js v4 , you can use ES6's [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
var my_name = 'John';
var s = `hello ${my_name}, how are you doing`;
console.log(s); // prints hello John, how are you doing
```

You need to wrap string within backtick `` ` `` instead of `'`